# change applicationStorageDirectory for cordova and put it in a place that does not need root acess

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

Rooting an android device is a long tidy process.
Is it possible to store my cordova application data in an area that I can access easily ( without having to root my device ) ?

PS : The use case is saving files and pictures in the file system in a persistent way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to root the device. Cordova's libraries implementations already make use of Android's best practices. Check [the official guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html) for more info.

Comment: the local storage is suitable for simple text data. i want to save images and files in the file system.

Comment: I think you may want to re-read the article, and all the way down. You can use IndexedDB, WebSQL, or plugins